# Issue with Docker0 on Vagrant

Tags: docker, networking

I have an application that I have been deploying that gets the local ip address to open up ports for communication it does.  It is running on a vagrant / virtualbox setup.  Everything was good.  I recently installed docker to run a DB container.

What I am finding is that the existing application when it tries to get its IP Address is finding the docker0 address 172.x.x.x and things start breaking.  If I destroy the docker0 adapter (sudo ip link del docker0) things go back to working.

Is there a way so that when the java application asks for the ip address it does not return the docker address?

Answer (score 1):

Thats how docker works. You could run the Container in the Host-Network so it will use the "VM" IP.

```
docker run my_container --net=host
```

Comment: Just to be clear the program that is breaking isn't running in the container but in the VM.